# Multiple linear regression interactions

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression, interaction

[image: http://puu.sh/oBlt0/d6ef9eab0b.png]

When plotting the effects of two factors on the dependent variable, why do parallel lines like the ones illustrated in figure 44 show that there is no interaction between factor (i) and factor (j)? I understand that factor (j) for j=2 has a greater effect on the dependent variable than when j=1 regardless of factor i. But clearly from the graph it is noticeable that when i=2 there is a decrease in the effect of both js on the dependent variable. Does that not suffice to say that there is an interaction between the groups?